# a function to convert a list to an int?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of [2]
what function can I use in Haskell to extract out a 2 so I get an Int output instead of a list?

thanks

Comment: Do you also want [1,2,3] to become 123?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer is the [head](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3ahead) function.

Unfortunately, this will produce a run-time error if the list is empty, so it's probably better to pattern match like so:

```
case [2] of
  x:_ -> do something with x
  _   -> deal with the fact that the list is empty
```

Comment: I think you meant to use a parameter: "case y of ...", "not "case [2] of ...". Also you can directly match against an empty list, case y of [] -> ..., instead of the wildcard

Comment: I meant [2], because that's what OP gave as an example.

Comment: ...in which case the pattern match is quite redundant. :D Anyway, never mind, hopefully the OP will work it out

Comment: The `do` here is redundant, as your do-block has only one statement. That is, forall `m`, `do m` is reduces to `m`.

Comment: I meant "do something with x" rather than do "something with x".

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned what sort of behaviour you want from your function if it operates on a list with multiple values.

If you're only interested in the first element of the list, then as Alex R mentioned the Prelude function "head" can be used to get the head of a non-empty list.

In case of a possibly empty list, if you want to defer dealing with it until later on, you can wrap up the result in a Maybe type and return Nothing if the list is empty.

```
head' :: [a] -> Maybe a
head' [] = Nothing
head' (x:_) = Just x
```